# I have a text file but I only need to print certain aspects of the file

Tags: java

I have a text file that essentially resembles a student transcript but I only need to print the student, numbers of courses and then the courses in the this format:

Student A: # of courses

- Course title 1
- Course title 2
- etc.

Student B: # of courses

- Course title 1
- Course title 2
- etc.

Student C: # of courses

- Course title 1
- Course title 2
- etc.

This is a portion of the text file:

Student A,Grade,Credit

Computer Applications,A,1

Career Investigations Phase I,A,1

English 9,A,1

World History II,A,1

Earth Science,A,1

Spanish I,A,1

Art I,A,1

Health & PE 9,B,1

Computer Information Systems,A,1

English 10 Honors,A,1

Geometry,B,1

World History I,A,1

Biology,A,1

Spanish II,A,1

Art II,A,1

Health & PE 10,B,1

"Design, Multimedia, and Web Technologies",C,1

Virginia & United States History,A,1

Algebra II,A,1

Chemistry I,A,1

Spanish III,A,1

Entrepreneurship Education,A,1

Advanced Entrepreneurship Education,A,1

Honors English 12,A,1

Economics and Personal Finance,A,1

AP English Language and Composition,A,1

AP Government and Politics: US,A,1

Mathematical Analysis/Pre-Calculus,A,1

Physics I,A,1

Introduction to Fashion Careers,A,1

Introduction to Culinary Arts,A,1

Career Interpretation - Phase II,A,1

My code so far just print the entire file. I've tried using system.out.println()
in the other places but nothing works. This is my code currently.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Phase1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new 
    FileReader("C:\\Users\\coderva.org\\Downloads\\FakeData.csv"));
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    while(file.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = file.nextLine();
        String[] lines = line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");

        System.out.println(line);
    }  
}

class Course
{
private char grade;
private double credit;
private String title;

public Course()
{
    title = "";
    grade = 'I';
    credit = 0;
}

public Course(String title, char grade, double credit)
{
    this.title= title;
    this.grade = grade; 
    this.credit = credit; 
}

public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}
public char getGrade()
{
    return grade;
}

public double getCredit()
{
    return credit;
}

public String toString()
{
    return title + " " + grade + " " + credit;
}
}

class  Student
{
private String name;
private ArrayList<Course> courses;
public Student()
{

    name = null;
    courses = null;
}

public Student(String name, ArrayList<Course> courses)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.courses = courses;
}

public void setName(String name) 
{
    this.name = name;
}

public void setCourses(ArrayList<Course> courses) 
{
    this.courses = courses;
}

public String getName() 
{
    return name;
}

public ArrayList<Course> getCourses() 
{
    return courses;
}
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve... Can you give more detail?

Comment: An example of the file contents would be helpful, we can't help you interpret the data if we don't know what the data looks like.

Comment: I added in a portion of the file

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so in your code, you created a main class called Phase1, a course class called Course, and a student class called Student. The idea behind creating these classes is correct. Basically, in your main class, you want to run through each line of the input file and parse the contents. You need to determine if the line of the input file is a new student or a course that will be added to the current student. If the line contains a new student, you need to create a new student object using your Student class. Otherwise, you need to add a new course, using your course class, to add to a student's list of classes. Once you have parsed the whole file, you can then loop through the list of students and the list of courses that each student has.

Phase1 Class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Phase1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileReader("data.txt"));
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        int currStudent = -1;

        while(file.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = file.nextLine();
            String[] split = new String[3];

            //Parse the line input, check if a course name has a comma (it has a comma if it is in quotation marks), otherwise proceed normally
            if(line.indexOf('"') == -1) {
                split = line.split(",");
            } else {
                split[0] = line.substring(line.indexOf('"')+1, line.lastIndexOf('"'));
                split[1] = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf('"')+2, line.lastIndexOf(','));
                split[2] = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(',')+1,line.length());
            }

            //If the line contains a new student, create the student
            if(split[0].contains("Student")) {
                students.add(new Student(split[0],new ArrayList<Course>()));
                currStudent++;
                continue;
            }

            //Add course to the current student
            students.get(currStudent).addCourse(split[0], split[1].charAt(0), Double.parseDouble(split[2]));
        }

        //Print all students
        for(Student s : students) {
            System.out.println(s.getName() + ": " + s.getCourses().size());
            //Print all courses for each student
            for(Course c : s.getCourses()) {
                System.out.println(c.getTitle());
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        file.close();
    }
}
```

Course Class (Same as yours above):

```
public class Course
{
    private char grade;
    private double credit;
    private String title;

    public Course() {
        title = "";
        grade = 'I';
        credit = 0;
    }

    public Course(String title, char grade, double credit) {
        this.title= title;
        this.grade = grade; 
        this.credit = credit; 
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public char getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public double getCredit() {
        return credit;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return title + " " + grade + " " + credit;
    }
}
```

Student Class (Slightly modified - Changed setCourses to addCourse):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Course> courses;

    public Student() {

        name = null;
        courses = null;
    }

    public Student(String name, ArrayList<Course> courses) {
        this.name = name;
        this.courses = courses;
    }

    public void setName(String name)  {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addCourse(String title, char grade, double credit) {
        this.courses.add(new Course(title,grade,credit));
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public ArrayList<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions about understanding the code!

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I understand the concept behind what you've done. The only question I have now is that I still get errors on 'public class student' and 'public class Course'. Should I make them sub classes of Phase 1?

Comment: I had them separated into 3 separate files in the same package but you could make them subclasses as well